# Code optimization with if condition check along with replaceAll

Tags: java, string, if-statement, replace

I have a string in which I have to check for some if conditions and do some replace operations as follows,

```
for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
    if(name[i].contains("sometext")){
       name[i] = name[i].replaceAll("someregexpattern","replacementtexthere");
    }
}
```

Instead of checking for the presence of 'sometext' every time using the 'if' condition, can I simply put it as follows,

```
for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
       name[i] = name[i].replaceAll("someregexpattern","replacementtexthere");
}
```

Anyway, if the string 'name' does not contain the 'regexpattern' means, it wont replace anything. So, does the if condition has any significance in terms of performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That will likely depend on how often the if condition is true (assuming `.contains` is cheaper than a `.replaceAll`). You'd be best of testing this for your particular use case,  methinks.

Comment: replaceall should be replaceAll. Your code compiling?

Comment: @Achintya Jha - That was a Typo. Corrected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be valid only if `sometext` is the same as `someregexpattern`. Else, the `if` condition does matter.

Say your `someregexpattern` is indeed present in the string, but your `if` condition evalutes to `false`, in that case, you're not supposed to do the replacement. But if you remove the `if` statement, then the replacement will happen, which is not quite the same.

**E.g:-** To help you understand better.

```
String testCondition = "dontReplace";
        String myString = "Hi, I'm SO";
        String regex = "SO";
        String replacement = "Not SO";

        if(myString.contains(testCondition)){
            myString = myString.replaceAll(regex, replacement); // stays "Hi, I'm SO"
        }

        myString = myString.replaceAll(regex, replacement); // Becomes "Hi, I'm Not SO"
```

As you see, the requirement was that the `String` replacement should not happen because the condition was `dontReplace`, but since the `if` was removed, the replacement happened, even though it wasn't supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

"If" itself won't affect performance.
Though function calls are pretty cheap nowadays, String.contains() will do 4-5 more function calls.

However, the former variant is better readable and less bug-prone.

Answer (score 0):

"any significance in terms of performance" also depends on how often that entire thing is executed in your software.

A profiler run (via [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) or so) will show you whether a significant part of your execution time is spent in `String#replaceAll()`. If it isn't, you won't get significant improvements by optimizing it. That sounds obvious, but it's all too often forgotten.

And if optimization won't bring significant gains, you'll almost always be better off with choosing the more readable variant of the code.